# How do I configure Hibernate to work in Karaf JPA Example?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am wanting to understand this [Karaf JPA example](https://github.com/apache/karaf/tree/master/examples/karaf-jpa-example).

When I follow the instructions to add features and run the bundles for eclipseLink, the example works correctly.

However, if I try to use Hibernate, it doesn't work. I don't know Hibernate / H2 well enough to know what I am missing.  When I run `feature:install karaf-jpa-example-provider-ds-hibernate`, I see this in the log:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: booking-hibernate] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

`diag` returns this information:

```
Status: Waiting
Declarative Services
org.apache.karaf.examples.jpa.provider.ds.hibernate.BookingServiceImpl (1) missing references: jpaTemplate
```

The karaf and H2 installs are new and empty. My suspicion is that there is something in H2 I need to do but I have no experience with this db.

**Edit**:
Using the `blueprint` example, again eclipseLink works and Hibernate does not.  Performing this command: `feature:install karaf-jpa-example-provider-blueprint-hibernate` causes this error in the log:

```
ERROR [features-2-thread-1] Bundle org.apache.aries.jpa.container [72] EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch. (javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: booking-hibernate] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory)
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: booking-hibernate] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

And this is the diag:

```
Missing dependencies:
(&(osgi.unit.name=booking-hibernate) 
(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManager))
```

**Edit #2**: I am using JDK11 (11.0.2).

thanks,
jon

Comment: Hope you have initialized a `contructor` with `jpaTemplate` parameter in `BookingServiceImpl`

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the code - I will try that though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is JDK11.  I have moved to JDK8 and it is working.

This is the post that clued me in: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12924